# Apply custom function to entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which call another one.

The objective is, by calling function get_substr  to extract a substring based on a position of the nth occurence of a character

```
def find_nth(string, char, n):
   start = string.find(char)
   while start >= 0 and n > 1:
      start = string.find(char, start+len(char))
      n -= 1
return start
def get_substr(string,char,n):
   if n == 1:
      return string[0:find_nth(string,char,n)]
   else:
      return string[find_nth(string,char,n-1)+len(char):find_nth(string,char,n)]
```

The function works.
Now I want to apply it on a dataframe by doing this.

```
df_g['F'] = df_g.apply(lambda x: get_substr(x['EQ'],'-',1))
```

I get on error:

```
KeyError: 'EQ'
```

I don't understand it as df_g['EQ'] exists.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. It does not exist probably. Maybe it's just written with whitespace somewhere? But without seeing the data I can only guess. You can see the column names of your df when using `df_g.columns`. Maybe you see whitespace there in the column name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about `axis=1`, without that function is applied to each *column* rather than each *row*. Consider simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[3,4]})
df['Z'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['A']*100,axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
   A  B    Z
0  1  3  100
1  2  4  200
```

As side note if you are working with value from single column you might use `pandas.Series.apply` rather than `pandas.DataFrame.apply`, in above example it would mean

```
df['Z'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x:x*100)
```

in place of

```
df['Z'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['A']*100,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried that: df_g['F'] = df_g.apply(lambda x: get_substr(string = x['EQ'], axis = 1, char= '-', n=1)), but it still not working. :-(

Comment: `axis` is argument for `apply`, not for `get_substr`